# adding static data to existing listView where data is populated from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have the following codes to add data from sqlite to the listView. (The code works)  However, I want to have static data on the listView and also have the function on adding from sqlite. Meaning that, I want to do a listView with data "A", "B","C" as default. So when user clicks on the "add" function user is able to add the data into sqlite and display into the same listView where the "A","B","C" data is. 
Please help.

Comment: You want to add default value for your listview? Just add A, B, C after listView.setAdapter(adapter); -> list.add(A), list.add(B), list.add(C)

Comment: @nightmaregiba  list.add("Singapore","4.772",R.mipmap.newsgd); this is the data i want to add, but i have a error, cannot resolve method 'add(java.lang.String, java.lang.String,int) please help thank you

Comment: you mean that the first 3 rows is different in data type from other?

Comment: is of the same data type

Answer (score 2):

**step 1**

declare one empty arraylist then add static data like in your case A,B,C and fill adapter with this data.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add("A");
            arrayList.add("B");
            arrayList.add("C");

MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this);
listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
myAdapter.addItem(arrayList);
```

in Adapter add this function

```
public void addItem(ArrayList<String> arraylist){
   this.arraylist = arraylist;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

**step 2**

in your add item function do 2 things

1 add those data in your database.

2 add those data into arraylist that you have created in step 1, and add it to adapter like below code.

```
databaseHelper.addData("D");
arrayList.add("D");
myAdapter.addItem(arrayList);
```

**step 3**

check after this when you come second time in screen check whether database has data init if yes then modify step one like below

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
                arrayList.add("A");
                arrayList.add("B");
                arrayList.add("C");

 MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this);
 listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);

if(databaseHelper.getDataList()!=null &databaseHelper.getDataList().size()>0{
    arrayList.addAll(databaseHelper.getDataList());
    myAdapter.addItem(arrayList);
 }else{
    myAdapter.addItem(arrayList);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you used `imageViewToByte()` for change ImageView to byte, but R.mipmap.newsgd is not ImageView, it resource

Answer (score 0):

Just add A, B, C after listView.setAdapter(adapter); -> list.add(A), list.add(B), list.add(C)

Ex:

```
list.add(new Food(someId, "Singapore","4.772",R.mipmap.newsgd, ...));
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

All you do is :-

```
    //get all data
    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        byte [] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

        list.add(new Food(id,name,price,image));
    }
    // Adding your three items for the list
    list.add(new food(your_id_for_A,your_name_for_A,your_price_for_A,your_image_for_A));
    list.add(new food(your_id_for_B,your_name_for_B,your_price_for_B,your_image_for_B));
    list.add(new food(your_id_for_C,your_name_for_C,your_price_for_C,your_image_for_C));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Noting that you may have to be a little careful with what id you provide and how you subsequently handle that id as you may have to distinguish between a row from the database as opposed to an added row.

Comment: sorry, when i add :  "list.add(new Food(50,"Singapore","4.772",R.mipmap.newsgd));" it still have error

Comment: The error still falls on the data type. Please suggest how can i do it. thank you

Comment: @awa that's a completely different question. I believe `list.add(new food(-10,"Singapore","4.772",new byte[]{0});` would work though.